# Bootstrap modal reset not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xjmf8qqt/7/

I'm trying to reset the data in Bootstrap Modal window once "Add" or "Cancel" is clicked through the following code but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

The modal window appears when the "Add Column" button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `clone` the modal each time you perform an operation (I follow this approach) and use a refference instead, for example:

```
var modal = $('#myModal').clone().modal();

// ...

modal.on('click', '#modalAdd', function(e){
    //...
});
```

[Check this updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/xjmf8qqt/8/) and add column.